# trigger external script and load content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I triggered the external .js function using $.getScript, after it's done, i am loading the content to 'div' element ('Result'). So after everything is done, i would like to perform other function like say for example alert the downloaded content (eg: #items). But, when i do alert, i don't think the whole content is yet downloaded, so it's not giving me the fully downloaded content. How can i achieve it?

```
$.getScript( "../js/script.js" )
          .done(function( script, textStatus ) {            
            load(function(){                
                $('Result').html();

            });
            alert($('#items').html());
          })
          .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
            alert( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
          }); 

function load(callback)
    {
         $("#Result").load("/somepage.aspx", function (response, status, xhr){
          if ( status == "error" ) {
            var msg = "error: ";
            $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
          }
          if(callback){
            callback();
          }
        });                                         
    };  

<div id="Result"></div>    
<div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: What are the contents of script.js? What is `$('Result').html();` suppose to do?

Comment: @Brant: please see the updated script. I am downloading the content in 'Result' div.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your code is in right way, because you get the `js`, but on `done`, you give the html of `#result`, then alert html of `#item`! this doesn't makes any sense to me. Also what is job of `load` function that you wrote below the `$.getScript`?

**Update**
So, you made some update, I think you want to fetch one page, without any postback, isn't it?

Comment: yes, i am fetching other page content. the thing is, after loading the content, i want to do something with that content. i can see my content being loaded, but just can't access the element yet when i do alert.

Comment: please answer this, do you want to navigate users to another page, without postback, and on that page you have some `js` (for example some jquery plugin) and the problem is, this `js` codes, dosn't work when you load the page, using `ajax`? (so you decided to fetch the `script` file to fix this), am I right?

Comment: well, i don't have any plugins. i am simply downloading contents from another page in 'Result' div. Everything works. The content is there. But, when i call load() and do alert i still can't see the downloaded contents yet.

Comment: If you mean this line `alert($('#items').html());`, where is `#items` ? in loaded content? Also please answer, why you decided to using `$.getScript`?

Comment: yes you are right that #items is part of loaded content. I used $.getScript to trigger the functions inside it where i have functions that dynamically add elements. Without doing $.getScript, i can't get those dynamic elements.

Comment: did you mean, the `#items` will be added by `js` to the target page?

Answer (score 0):

if downloaded script is in turn downloading something else, then most likely it's being done async. Which means you need to make the following changes:

wrap the external script in function

do getScript

upon completion invoke that function with parameter containing a callback function

inside this callback function do alert

attach event handler in external script's function to whatever that is downloading the content to call that parameter.

so for example you would do

```
      load(function(){                
            $('Result').html();
             wrapperFunction(function(){
               alert($('#items').html());  
             });
        });
```

and in script at `../js/script.js`

you would write

```
     function wrapperFunction(cb) {
     ..
      .done(function( ) {            
         cb();
      });
     ..
     }
```

Comment: i tried to do the way you have explained, instead i get alert "Triggered ajaxError handler."

Comment: Is url correct is there anpther error like cors in console. This error is coming fro  code that runs on fail. `fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) { alert( "Triggered ajaxError handler." ); });`

Comment: So it has nothing to do from what's inside done of getscript

Answer (score 0):

So, after some chat, here is my solution, hope this help:
I made 2 `.html` files, `a.html` and `b.html`.

Content of `a.html`:

```
<div></div>
<script>
    $.getScript("main.js", function() {
        $("div").load("b.html #items");
    });
</script>
```

And `b.html`:

```
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also content of `main.js` file:

```
$('<div></div>', {
    text: 'I am alive !!!',
    id: '#items'
}).appendTo('body');
```

and when I open the `a.html`, I can see `I am alive !!!`.

**Edit**:

Please note, I didn't add link of `main.js` to `a.html`.

**UPDATE**, same result with this code:

```
$.getScript("main.js").done(function() {
        load();
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        alert("Triggered ajaxError handler.");
    });

    function load() {            
        $("#Result").load("b.html #items", function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "error: ";
                $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: I am not sure if i can do that way cos i have to change a lot of code. Please find the update. i tried to use .done, may be i am not doing it the right way?

Comment: Bro, you need to load html, after loading js file. you wrote alert($('#items')), but you didn't provide source of #items. you need to load/find #items from loaded content, not loaded js. $.getScript just load the js files. not html content. you need to load html, after loading js

Comment: thnks for all the suggestions. The thing is i had to wait before that load() is completely executed. for instance, if i do alert after load(), i get all the contents.

Comment: your welcome, I'm here for help. look, normally you need to call `load` for fetching content, and then use `$.getScript` for fetching js files first, but in your case, you need to fetch the js, because  you need to run the code, after fetching the content. so, you need to run `$.getScript`, and on done, call `load` method and provide specific `id` (in your case `#items`), and on done, you are done !, just use the returned content (as I append to the `#Result`). what is the problem with this way?